# KeyCloak User Credentials Encryption

Tags: encryption, ldap, openid, keycloak, openid-connect

I am using KeyCloak to automatically import the users included to an existing LDAP. Right now, I need to know how do the KeyCloak communicate to the LDAP. Specifically how do the KeyCloak pass the password to LDAP to authenticate the user credentials.

I tried to search all over the internet but I cannot find a forum, blog, or documentation about this. I need this to pass our security requirement.

Comment: it depends, if you use ldaps then that should be secure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the protocol used.

When adding an LDAP user federation, it is possible to use both `ldap` and `ldaps` protocols.

When setting the `Connection URL` to `ldap://ldapserver.domain.com`,
the [ldap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) protocol is used and Keycloak communicates to the server via port 389 (by default), which means all data pulled from the LDAP server will be through plain-text, including passwords whenever authentication requests are made.

On the other hand, setting the `Connection URL` to `ldaps://ldapserver.domain.com`, would make use of `LDAP over SSL/TLS` (not to be confused with [LDAP+STARTTLS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encrypt-openldap-connections-using-starttls), which is another way of encrypting LDAP communication) and Keycloak communicates to the server via port 636 (by default). Which would mean all communication between Keycloak and the LDAP server would be via an encrypted SSL/TLS tunnel, similiar to how a browser and an `HTTPS` website communicates.

> **14.3.4. Connect to LDAP over SSL**
>
> When you configure a secured connection URL to your LDAP store(for
>   example ldaps://myhost.com:636 ), Keycloak will use SSL for the
>   communication with LDAP server. ...

Regarding passwords, which appears to be OP's specific concern, according to the documentation, passwords are sent to the provide as-is, which of course are transmitted through encrypted TLS tunnels if `ldaps` is used.

> **14.3.7. Password Hashing**
>
> When the password of user is updated from Keycloak and sent to LDAP,
>   it is always sent in plain-text. This is different from updating the
>   password to built-in Keycloak database, when the hashing and salting
>   is applied to the password before it is sent to DB. In the case of
>   LDAP, the Keycloak relies on the LDAP server to provide hashing and
>   salting of passwords.
>
> Most of LDAP servers (Microsoft Active Directory, RHDS, FreeIPA)
>   provide this by default. Some others (OpenLDAP, ApacheDS) may store
>   the passwords in plain-text by default and you may need to explicitly
>   enable password hashing for them. See the documentation of your LDAP
>   server more details.

Answer (score 5):

Keycloak communicates with the LDAP-compliant directory service via (drumroll, please) LDAP protocol. Keycloak [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_admin/#_ldap) talk about Active Directory as the LDAP service but any LDAP-compliant server *could* work. LDAP as a protocol allows connections to be made to the server in an unencrypted mode as well as secure mode over SSL (aka LDAPS). Keycloak [supports](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_admin/#connect-to-ldap-over-ssl) LDAPS in addition to the plain old LDAP:

> **14.3.4. Connect to LDAP over SSL**
>
> When you configure a secured connection URL to your LDAP store(for example 
>   ldaps://myhost.com:636), Keycloak will use SSL for the communication with LDAP server.

Here are some configuration examples: [one](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/ldap) [two](https://codehumsafar.wordpress.com/tag/ldap-with-keycloak/)

Keycloak docs go on to say that when a password is updated in Keycloak and pushed back to LDAP, it is done so in plaintext. This is somewhat misleading. If you use LDAPS, the password is indeed sent as plaintext in some cases but it's wrapped in SSL as a transport layer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same concern when I discovered that when using Keycloak with OpenLDAP, the passwords are stored in cleartext in the LDAP server.

After looking for a long time into how to force OpenLDAP to hash passwords when it receives them, I found that this was only necessary if the client (Keycloak) doesn't support "LDAPv3 Password Modify Extended Operation".

If you want the passwords to be stored as a hash in the LDAP server, you should enable "LDAPv3 Password Modify Extended Operation" in the Advanced settings when configuring the LDAP connection in Keycloak.

Comment: Your answer helped me to solve my concern about OpenLDAP storing plain-text password.